# Fontawesome - display Binded string as Icon, not unicode value

Tags: wpf, xaml, font-awesome

Stucked a bit with a pretty simple problem.
In my app - I have a ComboBox with a list of FontAwesome icons.
I describe them like unicode in a text property of a TextBlock.
Like:

```
<ComboBoxItem Padding="2">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" 
               Text="&#xf039;"/>
</ComboBoxItem>
```

All good, I see the list of icons in the ComboBox.
Now, as a first item, I want to see the current assigned to the object icon, so I do like this:

```
<ComboBoxItem Padding="2">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" 
               Text="{Binding Icon}" />
</ComboBoxItem>
```

The binded value Icon holds string Icon = "& #xf039;" (without the space) and now, my first item, which is binded to Icon displays not the icon, but the unicode value of the icon. 
I pretty much can understand that it is happening because of it is getting saved as a string and is getting passed as a string, literally, but what can be a workaround from here? Include a converter I suppose would not  help. But What can help is to save value of Icon as some else, instead of string and what can be represented as a Text property.

Will be very appreciated for some clues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating the `Icon` string in code behind, it should contain a C# unicode character escape sequence instead of a XML (or XAML) unicode character escape sequence:

```
Icon = "\uF039";
```